# Exchange values stored in 2 columns of a table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table as below:

items:

```
name VARCHAR(50), //STORES Item's Name
brand VARCHAR(50), //STORES Item's Brand
sales_rate DOUBLE(8,2),
PK(name, brand)
```

This table's primary key is foreign key to other tables in the database.

Now my problem is that user by mistake inserted the item's name in the `brand` column and item's brand in the `name` column. So my question is how can I write an update query to swap the values of the columns `name` and `brand`?

Comment: Set a = x, set b = a, set x = b. Note that money is normally DECIMAL

Comment: @Strawberry how to do it in SQL?

Comment: Are all the values incorrect?

Comment: @RahulTripathi no just value or 3 rows in more than 350 rows

Comment: do the other tables that reference the primary key also need to be updated?

Comment: @IanKenney no as they are ON UPDATE CASCADE

Comment: @Blip By issuing 3 queries.

Comment: @Strawberry could you explain the same in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET x=(@temp:=x), x = y, y = @temp
where somecondition;
```

Since you  commented that only 3 rows are affected then you have to add `somecondition`

Comment: @Strawberry:- The only thing which OP might have to change is to add a logic to JOIN the tables. (*I would have added that as well but since I dont have enough info about that so left it as it is*)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that

```
UPDATE `items`
   SET name=(@temp:=name), name= brand, brand = @temp
   WHERE (name, brand) = ('somebrand', 'somename');
```

it works..

Comment: Your answer is same as Rahul's only you have added the column names according to my table. Thanks a lot for answering.